# Remove "Project Specific Settings" for all projects in an Eclipse workspace at once?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, project-settings

I have a workspace that contains at least 30 individual Eclipse "project" folders. I need to remove the Java Compiler->Project Specific Settings for every project in the workspace.

Thus far, I have been manually going to each project, opening its properties and unchecking the "Enable project specific settings" box and applying my changes.  This takes ages.  I'm looking for a way to globally uncheck that box for all projects in my workspace.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same nagging problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Eclipse offer a UI for that, but you can simply delete the settings file (with or without closing Eclipse first)

```
cd /workspace/
rm */.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

For doing some automation in this area, the [preference recorder and workspace mechanics](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/wiki/PreferenceRecorder)  might be a solution.